# create sets of similar dataframes from one dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a dataframe that looks like this

```
name   x      y      z   ...
a      test   True   0
b      set    False  0
c      set    True   1
b      fix    True   1
c      set    False  0
```

i wanted to create multiple set of dfs with diff conditions

> first df - for name = "..." that also satisfies the condition x = set

> second df - for name = "..." that also satisfies the condition y = True

> third df - for name = "..." that also satisfies the condition z = 1

ideally to have three df's for specific names

edit: i'm sorry, i should've mentioned it before. i know i could subset and copy paste the commands, but i wanted to repeat this for 6-7 names and wanted something more efficient.

Comment: Are you just looking for new dataframes with the same columns, just a subset of the rows where the conditions hold true? Here is the user guide on selecting data: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: yeah, but I wanted the new dataframes for 6-7 different names. didn't want to copy paste the same commands 6-7 times, was looking for something more efficient.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```python
result = {}
for name in df.name.unique():
    name_df = df[df.name == name]
    result[name] = [
        name_df[name_df.x == 'set'],
        name_df[name_df.y],
        name_df[name_df.z == 1]
    ]
```

Comment: i know this, was looking for some shorter method

i have to repeat these commands for like 5-6 different names, and i dont want to copy paste these commands and was looking for something shorter, any easier way to solve it?

Comment: You don't have to copy paste them, you can use loops. Updated the answer.

Comment: Are you sure though that you really need separate dataframes for each name and condition? Usually you would be fine by filtering values on the fly, but of course that depends on the task you are trying to solve.

Comment: yeah, i need separate dfs and i'm very weak with loops. any idea on how to go about it?

Comment: how do i access those three dataframes for a specific name?

Comment: Like this: `result['a'][0]`

Comment: this worked, thanks alot! 

any idea on how to get better at for loops? i've been struggling at it for a while now